# How to load a local csv file into a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, csv

I am able to display the content from a csv file on a web page ( based on what I have found on this site), but how do I read the csv values into an array in JavaScript?

Let's say if I have a file in this CSV format:

Red, Green, Blue,,

Orange, Yellow, Black,,

Indigo, purple, navy,, ...

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Perhaps you can try https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse

Comment: I deleted my earlier comments.  I am able to see an Array for each line of my csv file using Papa Parse.  I had to click on the small triangles to expand.  I don't know how to console.log to see the Arrays again.

Answer (score 2):

```
function UploadCSV() {
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
    if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            try{
                var table = $("<table />");
                var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = $("<tr />");
                    var cells = rows[i].split("|");
                    if (cells.length > 1) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                            var cell = $("<td />");
                            var td = cells[j].replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");
                            cell.text(td);
                            row.append(cell);
                        }
                        table.append(row);
                    }

                }
                $("#dvCSV").html('');
                $("#dvCSV").append(table);
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                $('#meessageBar1').text(e.message);
                $('#meessageBar1').fadeIn("slow", function () {
                    setTimeout(messageBar1Remove, 2000);
                });
            }
        }
        reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
    } else {
        $('#meessageBar1').text('This browser does not support HTML5.');
        $('#meessageBar1').fadeIn("slow", function () {
            setTimeout(messageBar1Remove, 2000);
        });
    }
}
```

}

This is a snippet I used to read data from a PIPE ('|') seperated csv file data into HTML table, you can `var cells = rows[i].split("|");` change this line whatever your csv file use as seperator. Here I attach each cell data of each row into  of a table row, you can omit this and simply insert whole  data into an array. If this helps you, please mark it as accepted answer. Thank you.